# How to find the corresponding key value from the string inserted into a QMap?

Tags: qt

I have the following data structure.

```
QMap<int,QString> map;

map.insert(0x01,"HELLO");
map.insert(0x02,"FELLOW");
map.insert(0x83,"NESTLE");
map.insert(0x044,"KITKAT");

QString str="NESTLE";
```

My requirement is to retrieve the value -0x83 when the string - NESTLE is passed.
Basically, based on str value, I want to get the corresponding key value i.e. 0x83 in this example. How can I do so?

Answer (score 4):

I would do this:

```
[..]
QString str = "NESTLE";
int key = getKey(map, str); // should return 0x83 in your example.
[..]

int getKey(const QMap &map, const QString &value)
{
    foreach (QString v, map) {
        if (v == value)
           return map.key(value);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

UPDATE:

Or the key could be simply found, by:

```
int key = map.key("NESTLE");
```

Comment: Why do we iterate here? Why not just map.key(str); ?

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI, yeah:) Than you answered on your own question.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches, depending on how many items are in the map.

If the map has few items (say <20), you can search for the key using `map.key()`. This  performs a linear search over all items, and thus will perform badly for large maps due to O(N) complexity of such a search.

Alternatively, you can implement a bidirectional map. Shown below is a very trivial variant that only works for distinct T1 and T2. Note that there are no non-const index operators, since both maps would need to be modified. This would need a wrapper class.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2> class BiMap {
  QMap<T1, T2> m_map1;
  QMap<T2, T1> m_map2;
public:
  typedef QMap<T1, T2>::iterator iterator1;
  typedef QMap<T1, T2>::const_iterator const_iterator1;
  typedef QMap<T2, T1>::iterator iterator2;
  typedef QMap<T2, T1>::const_iterator const_iterator2;
  iterator1 insert(const T1 & key, const T2 & value) {
    m_map2.insert(value, key);
    return m_map1.insert(key, value);
  }
  iterator2 insert(const T2 & key, const T1 & value) {
    m_map1.insert(value, key);
    return m_map2.insert(key, value);
  }
  const T1 & operator[](const T1 & key) const {
    return m_map1[key];
  }
  const T2 & operator[](const T2 & key) const {
    return m_map2[key];
  }
};

BiMap<int,QString> map;

map.insert(0x01, "HELLO");
map.insert(0x02, "FELLOW");
map.insert(0x83, "NESTLE");
map.insert(0x044, "KITKAT");

int key = map["NESTLE"];
```

Comment: Depending on the requirements, one could also use existing implementations like Boost bimap: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

C++ algorithm should work fine:

```cpp
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iostream>    

    QMap<int,QString> map;

    map.insert(0x01,"HELLO");
    map.insert(0x02,"FELLOW");
    map.insert(0x83,"NESTLE");
    map.insert(0x044,"KITKAT");

    QString str="NESTLE";
    
    auto it = std::find_if(map.begin(), map.end(),
                          [&str](const QString &p){ return p == str; });

     if(it != map.end())
        std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << it.key();
```