# access QMap element by its value not by its key

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

i want to access a QMap by it's value, but i don't want to iterate over it and find element with same value and use it's key,
is there anyway to find QMap key by it's content?
my code is :

```
    QMap<int, QVector<QString> >::iterator it;
QMap <QString, int> m_all_data;
```

i want to access to element of m_all_data with value of my `iterator` key;

Comment: no, you have to iterate

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the corresponding key value from the string inserted into a QMap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606159/how-to-find-the-corresponding-key-value-from-the-string-inserted-into-a-qmap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
const Key QMap::key ( const T & value ) const
```

which returns the first key with value value or

```
QList<Key> QMap::keys ( const T & value ) const
```

which returns a list containing all the keys in the map in ascending order.

But it is slow (linear time), because QMap's internal data structure is optimized for fast lookup by key, not by value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QMap::values` (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmap.html#values) to get the values.

This will give you a `QList` on which you can iterate through, and for the given value you can get the key using `QMap::key` (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmap.html#key) to get the key for the given value.

Comment: This will create a temporary container. The good answer is from @Nejat

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a second QMap with iterators pointing into the first map, i.e.

```
QMap<QString, int> m_all_data;
QMap<int, QList<QMap<QString, int>::iterator> > m_data_by_int;
```

Note that each `int` value would map to *list of* iterators since there may be multiple map entries with the same value. Using iterators avoids that you duplicate the `QString` data. You'd have to make sure to keep the two maps syncronized though, so it might be best to wrap the two maps into a 'bidirectional map' class.